# How to know which machine is running windows service

Tags: sql-server, windows-services

we have a table in sqlserver database. There is a windows service which picks up the record from this table where data is null. Process that record and updated current date. This service might have been installed on multiple developer's machine. Is that a way to find list of db users/ machine names where this service is running. If service is running on any of the machine, it is using same database and updating same table.

Comment: Have you tried SQL Profiler?

Comment: I am new to sql profiler. can you please tell me how to configure it to show activity on a particular table?

Comment: Please mention full version name that you are using.

Comment: SQL SERVER 2008 R2, SQL Server Profiler      10.50.1600.1
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.11.9600.16521
Microsoft .NET Framework      2.0.50727.5477
Operating System      6.1.7601

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open SQL Profiler => Events Selection Tab => Column Filters button.

DatabaseName : Like: "Target DB Name",
TextData : Like : "Target Table Name"

Hit Ok. Check: Show all columns => Check BatchCompleted,BatchStarting for HostName Column
=> Click Run

You'll be able to watch every transaction that is being made on the target table. However,
you won't be able to filter by which application is accessing the specified table(I believe
Application name is: SqlClient Data Provider ) 
**Unless** You've added `Application Name="My Application"` to the connection string of your application which is a windows service in your case.

Comment: Okay. I got this. 

"EventClass=Audit Logout"
"Application Name = Queue Reader SQL Queue Committer =(<MyDBNAME AND SCHEMA NAME>)"
"NTUserName= SqlSrvReplicationSer "
"LoginName=ASSEENONSCREEN\SqlSrvReplicationSer"
"ClientProcessId=8676 "

But how can I find system where windows process is running?

Comment: If you did exactly as I showed you, you'll find it on the last column "HostName" . That's why I asked to check on HostName actions in my answer

Comment: Yes I did the same. But HostName column has no value. I can see blank for this all rows.

Comment: Indeed. from the example you've posted above, that is a replication service running on the table which is running on the local server. that is why the hostname is blank

Comment: okay. but How do I find name of the replication? I would like to disable it.